# How to schedule the export (xls/csv/xlsx) report from SAP crystal report 2013 in to a particular location/folder/drive

Tags: crystal-reports

schedule the Export for reports from Crystal reports 2013 to a local drive or location.

I have CR 2013, I can schedule a report to run at particular time and access it via SAP CR server and I can download it. 
I am looking a option wherein the report is schedule to run at (lets say)  6:00 AM daily and the report is exported to a particular folder/path/location on the local system.

Expected results- Once I schedule a a report to run daily, the output should be exported to a file/location in the local system or shared drive in any format like csv/xls.

Answer (score 0):

There are several free or inexpensive 3rd-party Crystal Reports desktop schedulers listed [here](https://kenhamady.com/productlinks/default.html#desktopsched).

You can also develop such a solution yourself using the Crystal Reports runtime.

Comment: thank you!

Isn't there any options within CR itself? please advise

Comment: No such option within Crystal itself.